# Post filtering is returning blank page

Tags: posts, filters, sort

I embedded some code to generate post filters referencing an article at
https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/add-post-filters/ as displayed below:

```
<form class='post-filters'>
<select name="orderby">
<?php
  $orderby_options = array(
    'post_date' => 'Order By Date',
    'post_title' => 'Order By Title',
    'rand' => 'Random Order',
  );
  foreach( $orderby_options as $value => $label ) {
    echo "<option ".selected( $_GET['orderby'], $value )." 
    value='$value'>$label</option>";
  }
?>
</select>
<select name="order">
<?php
 $order_options = array(
 'DESC' => 'Descending',
 'ASC' => 'Ascending',
);
foreach( $order_options as $value => $label ) {
  echo "<option ".selected( $_GET['order'], $value )." 
  value='$value'>$label</option>";
}
?>
</select>
<input type='submit' value='Filter!'>
</form>
```

Consequently, the page the same code is embedded only returns a blank page showing no code in the source view. I also used Search & Filter plugin only to get the same blank page.

I cannot resolve this issue alone. Please someone help me correct the code.

After editing front-page.php based on the comments given:

```
      <?php echo get_template_part('head') ?>
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
    <?php get_header(); ?>
    <main>
        <div id="main">
            <div class="outer">
                <ul class="breadcrumb"><?php breadcrumb() ?></ul>
                <form class="post-filters"><select name="orderby"><?php
                    $orderby_options = array(
                        'post_date' => 'Order By Date',
                        'title' => 'Order By Title',
                        'rand' => 'Random Order'
                    );
                    $orderby = isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_GET['orderby'] ) : 'default value';
                    foreach($orderby_options as $value => $label):
                        echo '<option '.selected($orderby, $value, false).' value="'.$value.'">'.$label.'</option>';
                    endforeach;
                ?>
                    <input type="submit" value="Filter">
                </form>
                <div class="inner">
                    <?php
                        $filter = array('parent' => 0, 'hide_empty' => 0, 'exclude' => (5));
                        $categories = get_categories($filter);
                        shuffle($categories);
                        if($categories):
                            foreach($categories as $category):
                                $catName = $category->cat_name;
                                $catFilter = array(
                                    'category_name' => $catName
                                );
                                echo '<div class="section"><section><h2 data-aos="fade-up">'.$catName.'</h2>'.category_description(get_cat_ID($catName)).'<div class="wrapper">';
                                $catquery = new WP_Query($catFilter);
                                if($catquery->have_posts()):
                                    while($catquery->have_posts()): $catquery->the_post();
                                            if(has_post_thumbnail()){
                                                echo '<div class="item" data-aos="fade-down"><a href="'.get_the_permalink().'"><h3>'.get_the_post_thumbnail().'<span class="date">'.get_the_date().'</span></h3>'.'<dl><dt>'.get_the_title().'</dt><dd>'.get_the_content().'</dd></dl></a></div>';
                                            }else{
                                                echo '<div class="item" data-aos="fade-down"><a href="'.get_the_permalink().'"><h3>No Image Available<span class="date">'.get_the_date().'</span></h3>'.'<dl><dt>'.get_the_title().'</dt><dd>'.get_the_content().'</dd></dl></a></div>';
                                            }
                                    endwhile;
                                endif;
                                echo '</div></section></div>';
                                wp_reset_postdata();
                            endforeach;
                        endif;
                    ?>
                </div>
                <div class="banner-ads" data-aos="fade-down"><section><?php the_ad_group(12); ?></section></div>
                <?php
                    $catObj = get_category_by_slug('news');
                    $catName = $catObj->name;
                    echo '<div class="inner" id="'.$catName.'"><div class="wrapper"><h2 data-aos="fade-up">'.$catName.'</h2>';
                    $catquery = new WP_Query('category_name="news"');
                    if($catquery->have_posts()):
                        while($catquery->have_posts()): $catquery->the_post();
                            if(has_post_thumbnail()){
                                echo '<dl data-aos="fade-right"><dt style="background: url('.get_the_post_thumbnail_url().')"></dt>';
                            }else{
                                echo '<dl data-aos="fade-right"><dt><span>No Image Available</span></dt>';
                            }
                            echo '<dd>'.'<span class="date">'.get_the_date().'</span><br class="sp">';
                            $tags = get_the_tags();
                            foreach($tags as $tag){
                                $tagName = $tag->name;
                                echo '<span class="tag">'.$tagName.'</span>';
                            }
                            echo get_the_content().'</dd></dl>';
                        endwhile;
                    endif;
                    echo '</div></div>';
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
    <?php get_footer(); ?>
</body>
```

Comment: `selected()` by default echoes the output and in your `selected()` calls, the third parameter should be `false`. E.g. `selected( $_GET['orderby'], $value, false )`

Comment: passing the false parameter resulted in the blank page. Something I noticed is the code inspection screen returns the following message just after <select name='orderby'>:

Notice:  Undefined index: orderby in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test/wp-content/themes/wwwares/front-page.php on line 17

Comment: In that case, in addition to what I've said in my previous comment, use something like `$_GET['orderby'] ?? 'default value'` if you're on PHP 7. Or better, assign them to custom variables - e.g. `$orderby = isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_GET['orderby'] ) : 'default value';` and use `$orderby` in the `selected()` call.

Comment: I tried assigning the conditional check to $orderby variable in the selected() call. The page was still blank and this time all the code inside <body> was wiped out...??

Comment: Can you show the whole code in your template (`front-page.php`)?

Comment: @SallyCJ I included the modified code in the question. The custom loops are working as they are expected to. Please let me know any potential error.

Comment: Can you just please show the whole code there? Or at least everything in between the `<main>` and `</main>`? Because the one that you've shown is just fine.

Comment: @SallyCJ Thank you for checking my code. I now included the whole code from font-page.php in my question as is.

Comment: Other than in the filters form, I don't see where else the `orderby` option being used in your code. Do you use it in your `functions.php` file? But your code, other than the `category_description(get_cat_ID($catName))` which should just be `$category->description`, is fine. Are you still seeing PHP notices/warnings printed on the page?

Comment: And if enabled, try clearing your site cache.

Comment: Changing the value of the orderby property in the $catFilter array resulted in the blank page so I had it removed from the code. I replaced the category_description with $category->description, but then again the code still results in the blank page.

I had a feeling that there is something fundamentally incorrect about the way the site was set up, but clearing the cache made no change and while checking through the settings in the admin screen nothing seems out of order...

Comment: No, I was just saying that you don't need to use `category_description()` to display the category description since you can access it from the `$category` object. Similarly with the `selected()`, I was just saying that you're not using the proper syntax in your context.

Comment: "Changing the value of the orderby property in the $catFilter array resulted in the blank page" - are you sure? It should look like this: `$catFilter = array( 'category_name' => $catName, 'orderby' => $orderby );` and that shouldn't cause any errors..

Comment: I'm clear on the use of the $category object property. 

Setting 'orderby' => $orderby results in the blank page wiping out the whole code inside the <body> element in the Inspect screen, so the root cause may be something else.

Comment: Try to just put it there, enable WordPress [debugging](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/), view the page, then check the error log file for relevant lines. You could also deactivate all plugins.

Comment: The blank page no longer shows after I changed Your Home Page Displays back to 'Your Latest Posts', but I don't know why and the filter still doesn't work. Enabling Debug Mode doesn't return an error either.

Comment: It turned out the problem was twofold. The blank page issue was resolved once the Your Homepage Displays setting was reset to the latest posts whereas the post filter began working once $orderby was set as the orderby parameter in the argument declaration of WP_Query as pointed out by @SallyCJ. I posted the code for the filter in the answer section.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the cause of this lingering filter problem was to do with the way WordPress was set up as well as the argument of `WP_Query`. Once I changed the *Your Homepage Displays* setting to the latest posts and renamed `front-page.php` to be `index.php`, the filter began working and the blank page no longer showed.

Concerning the post filter, declaring the orderby parameter as part of the argument of `WP_Query` got it working. The code for the filter is as follows:

```
<form class="post-filters">
    <select name="orderby">
        <?php
            $orderby_options = array(
                'post_date' => 'Order By Date',
                'post_title' => 'Order By Title',
                'rand' => 'Random Order'
            );
            foreach($orderby_options as $value => $label):
                echo '<option '.selected($_GET['orderby'], $value, false).' value="'.$value.'">'.$label.'</option>';
            endforeach;
        ?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Filter">
</form>
```

Comment: Yes and more specifically, the front page template will *not* be used if a registered WordPress query var (e.g. `orderby`) presents in the request URL. Instead, the `home.php` or `index.php` template will be used by default. But even if that's the case, the page (e.g. `example.com/?orderby=title`) shouldn't be blank, unless your theme doesn't have the home/index template or that it contains/causes errors. Also, the third parameter for the `selected()` should be `false` in your context.

Answer (score 0):

You are removing necessary parts of the code, you started opening `form` and `select` HTML elements, but you never close them, use the full code:

```
<form class='post-filters'>
    <select name="orderby">
        <?php
            $orderby_options = array(
                'post_date' => 'Order By Date',
                'post_title' => 'Order By Title',
                'rand' => 'Random Order',
            );
            foreach( $orderby_options as $value => $label ) {
                echo "<option ".selected( $_GET['orderby'], $value )." value='$value'>$label</option>";
            }
        ?>
    </select>
    <select name="order">
        <?php
            $order_options = array(
                'DESC' => 'Descending',
                'ASC' => 'Ascending',
            );
            foreach( $order_options as $value => $label ) {
                echo "<option ".selected( $_GET['order'], $value )." value='$value'>$label</option>";
            }
        ?>
    </select>
    <select name="thumbnail">
        <?php
            $order_options = array(
                'all' => 'All Posts',
                'only_thumbnailed' => 'Posts With Thumbnails',
            );
            foreach( $order_options as $value => $label ) {
                echo "<option ".selected( $_GET['thumbnail'], $value )." value='$value'>$label</option>";
            }
        ?>
    </select>
    <input type='submit' value='Filter!'>
</form>
```

Then if you want to remove things you think you don't need, you can turn on the [Debug](https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG) to see what is falling and why you are getting a blank page, in this case, you are getting a blank page because your code is pretty incomplete and many things should be failing.

Comment: Sorry, I did not insert enough blank spaces when submitting the question. I edited the code and now it's showing the code including the closing tags. Turning on the Debug Mode results in the same blank page.